# Product stock status update on success order in magento

Tags: php, magento, solr, magento-1.7

I am using solr search in our project. I need to update the product stock status(In Stock/Out of Stock) in solr document on success order. I need to know the place/function where the product stock status is getting updates on success order.  i.e. If the product goes out of stock on success order, it should be update the product stock order as `out of stock`. Manual status changing from back-end is affecting in solr document. But on success order I need to update the status in solr document. Is there any observer/event for this? Please help me out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have seven event in the sales_order_model but if I am not wrong, the "save" event is the one that you need for such observer : *sales_order_save_before* or *sales_order_save_after*. With it you can check the status of the order and act accordingly.

Comment: OK I will check and let you know

Comment: Hi, after some struggle I competed this using `sales_order_save_after` event. Working fine. Thanks.